# Send a request to a distant server

Tags: xml, soap

I have an access on a site data information concerning legal companies.

I want to display this information on my site, to exploit them. They told me to use xmlrequest but I do not know how to actually submit the Siret number and retrieve the information

I have been told that it was a type system getdata.

They gave me a sample query

```
<xmlrequest>
    <header>
        <username>demo</username>
        <password>********</password>
        <operation>getcompanyinformation</operation>
        <language>EN</language>
        <country>FR</country>
        <chargereference>[Demonstration.aspx]</chargereference>
    </header>
    <body>
        <package>standard</package>
        <companynumber>NUMERO SIRET</companynumber>
    </body>
</xmlrequest>
```

I put this code on a page .xml
but when I load it in the browser, it just display the text without xml tags.

So I do not know how to send the message to the server and to receive the response.

Answer (score 0):

`to exploit them` ?

I guess you are using Google Chrome, right? By default, Chrome will XML as text. If you view source, the XML is there.

Comment: oh taht's right. but why i can not receive the information i requested? i do not know how the send the request

Comment: anybody is able to explain me why I have no answer from server just the text that is encoding in the xml file.?

Comment: install `XML Tree` Chrome Add-on. You will be able to read XML.

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me why i have no response  please?

I just want to get information from a distant server, I do not know how to send a message xml using soap i have found no tutorial on internet

Comment: any test link ? hard to know without codes & test links. I'm sure there are tutorials of building SOAP Requests online.

Comment: the test link is there http://creditsafe.fr/getdatainformation/Demonstration.aspx

Comment: moreover they gave me this https://www.creditsafe.fr/getdata/service/CSFRServices.asmx?WSDL but I do not know how to use this